# Assignment statement stored in a variable causes command not found error in Bash

Tags: bash

For example:

```
#!/bin/bash
sss='ls -l'
$sss
ttt='a=100'
$ttt
```

The output of `ls` is correct, however, the assignment statement will output an error message:

> line 5: a=100: command not found

Why the difference?

If assignment is not command, what is it? I mean what is the difference between explicit `a=100` and `a=100` expanded from variable, I mean, the bash sees the same thing `a=100`, right? Why they got different interpretation?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's because the output from variable expansion is run as a command, precisely get replaced in the command line as if you have inserted the content literally.

Here, you have `ttt='a=100'`, so when you do `$ttt` next, it will be simple  expanded as `a=100` and as this would be the command to run being the only parameter present. And the error is due to the obvious fact that this is not a valid command.

You can tack the expansion with some actual-valid command to get the expansion as that command's argument (e.g. `echo $ttt`), as you can imagine.

---

If you ever need to do assignments like that, leverage `declare`:

```
$ ttt='a=100'

$ declare "$ttt"

$ echo "$a"
100
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to execute code, use a function, not a parameter expansion.

```
$ sss () { ls -l; }
$ sss
foo.txt bar.txt
$ ttt () { a=100; }
$ ttt
$ printf '%d\n' "$a"
100
```

Answer (score 0):

Because `a=100` is not a command, and you can't evaluate assignments like that.

In order to properly evaluate the assignment try:

```
eval $ttt
```

Comment: Hi,Thank you for answering. But I got confused, if assignment is not command, what is it? I mean it is still not clear, what is the difference between explicit `a=100` and `a=100` expanded from variable, I mean, the bash sees the same thing `a=100`, right? Why it got different interpretation?

Comment: It didn't differentiate really. `command` for shell is one of alias, builtin, function, or an executable file either specified through a path or looked up through the list of directories specified by `$PATH`. In your case, `ls` was looked up and found in one of the directories of `$PATH`, however, `a=100` wasn't found.  Hence, 'command not found` error.

Comment: Why do you suggest `eval` to a newbie?